# Graphical object alignment

Tags: c#, xaml, alignment

I'm trying to do something very simple in Xaml but can't find the solution.

Would like to have 3 columns set this way:

1. Left column: contains an combobox that I want to be aligned on the left
2. Middle column: Contains a text from time to time. When displayed, want it to be centered in the remaining space.
3. Right column: Contains some Wrapping panel that I want aligned to the right.

So far I've done this:

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The Middle column Xaml is:

```
        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Name="UserInfoLogs" Text="{Binding Path=...}" />
        </WrapPanel>
```

It aligns correctly the left and right columns' elements, but when displaying the centered text it is naturally aligned to the left of the middle column.

thanks!

Comment: Can you post the xaml for the text container which is in the middle column?

Comment: if you have only one item in your column, you don't need a wrap panel.

Comment: True, I've setup a style on wrap panels, this is the reason. Still, this isn't the issue, I've tested without it and still the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it, you're just missing one ingredient;

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Text="Left"/>
   <!-- Most of the time just setting the HorizontalAlignment will suffice, 
        except when the TextBlock object is for whatever reason allowed to 
        stretch further than its contents. In which case TextAlignment will 
        align the Text within the Center of itself. -->
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Center" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Right"/>

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there, it's what SO is for. :)